# How much time is needed to restart a sticky service after it was killed?

Tags: android, android-service

How does the system know when it should restart a killed sticky service? How often does the system do this check? When I kill my sticky service, the system sometimes restarts it immediately, some times after few minutes or half hour.

Sticky services are said to be restarted by the system, but when? And is it 100% will be restarted or 99%?

Comment: all that depends on exact device firmware. About `100% will be restarted or 99%` I can say that in normal situation it is 100%, but in critical situation it might not be restarted.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. But why time for restarting so different?

Comment: maybe there are higher priority tasks to be done before restarting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a sticky service is killed, it will be restarted when the OS decides the reason it was killed is not valid anymore. E.g. if it was killed due to memory issues, it will be restarted when there is enough memory again.

> When system know when it should restart some killed services? How often system do this check? When i kill my service system some times restart it immediately some times after few minutes or half hover...START_STICKY said to system service will be restarted but when?

You should not concern yourself with this. The only thing that matters is that it *is* restarted *at some point*.

I have experience with sticky services and I can tell you the time it takes for a killed service to be restarted can heavily vary. Some times it will be near instantly, some times it may take a couple of minutes, some times an hour, some times more. It is reliant on a lot of factors like your device hardware, operating system logic, task scheduling, etc. You cannot predict it and your app should not depend on it.

> And is it 100% will be restarted or 99%?

I have never seen a sticky service being killed and *not* restarted later.